# Помогите реализовать клик на CardView и переход на Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, java-ee

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать что б при клике в RecyclerView на CardView открывался новый фрагмент. Я уже столько прочел но ни как не получается. Могу дать доступ к своему проекту на гитхабе что б подправили в нужном направлении.
Вот собственно сам гитхаб : https://github.com/Innerbloom/onClickListener

А вот сам код к котором должен реализовываться клик:

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {



public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    CardView cv;
    TextView fishName;
    TextView fishAbout;
    ImageView fishPhoto;

    ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    FragmentManager fm;



    PersonViewHolder(View itemView, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        fishName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.fish_name);
        fishAbout = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.fish_about);
        fishPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.fish_photo);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.fm = fm;


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        this.itemClickListener.OnClick(v, getLayoutPosition());
        }

        public void SetItemClickListener (ItemClickListener ic){
            this.itemClickListener = ic;
        }
    }


List<FishName> fishNames;
private FragmentManager FragManager;

public RVAdapter(List<FishName> fishNames){
    this.fishNames = fishNames;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
    PersonViewHolder personViewHolder = new PersonViewHolder(view);
    return personViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i, FragmentManager fm) {
    personViewHolder.fishName.setText(fishNames.get(i).name);
    personViewHolder.fishAbout.setText(fishNames.get(i).about);
    personViewHolder.fishPhoto.setImageResource(fishNames.get(i).photoId);


    personViewHolder.itemClickListener = (new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnClick(View v, int pos) {

        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return fishNames.size();
}
```

}

Comment: может вам лучше обрабатывать клик не в адаптере,а в самом созданном вами recyclerview? посмотрите [здесь, второй ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

Comment: не совсем понятно увы :(

Answer (score 1):

Вот изменение

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {

privat ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    CardView cv;
    TextView fishName;
    TextView fishAbout;
    ImageView fishPhoto;

    ItemClickListener itemClickListener;
    FragmentManager fm;


    //add parametr listener
    PersonViewHolder(View itemView, FragmentManager fm, ItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        fishName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.fish_name);
        fishAbout = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.fish_about);
        fishPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.fish_photo);

        //set listener
        itemClickListener = mItemClickListener;

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.fm = fm;


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //change getLayoutPosition() on getAdapterPosition()
         itemClickListener.OnClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }


List<FishName> fishNames;

public RVAdapter(List<FishName> fishNames, ItemClickListener mItemClickListener){
    this.itemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    this.fishNames = fishNames;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
    PersonViewHolder personViewHolder = new PersonViewHolder(view);
    return personViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i, FragmentManager fm) {
    personViewHolder.fishName.setText(fishNames.get(i).name);
    personViewHolder.fishAbout.setText(fishNames.get(i).about);
    personViewHolder.fishPhoto.setImageResource(fishNames.get(i).photoId);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return fishNames.size();
}
}
```

Лучше **уменьшить нагрузку на адаптер**, чтобы список работал как нужно.
Для этого наследуем **ItemClickListener** и выполняем в нем наши операции.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements ItemClickListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

  @Override
  void OnClick (View view, int pos){
    //TODO
  }
}
```

Comment: Что то ошибки выдает ((( http://joxi.ru/YmEKJyNT036x5A

Comment: @АртемМишуровский Так правильно, на вход должно быть 2 параметра. View и твой Listener

Comment: @АртемМишуровский `PersonViewHolder personViewHolder = new PersonViewHolder(view,itemClickListener);`